# How to pick a random word from a big file in python

Tags: python

I want to make a wordle game and a have this huge file with every 5 letterword. Now, I need to pick a random word from this file. Can I just make a list with all the words or won't this work because the list would be enormous and use a lot of memory. The words are seperated with a \n.

I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: You should know how much RAM you have (several GB i would guess) and how big the file is (I would guess less than 1MB). The size of the list will  be noticeably bigger than the file, but it should still be way below your RAM availability. And BTW, you could also just try it.

Comment: how big is "huge"?  there is only about 200,000 words in the English language. 5-letter words would be some fraction of that. that is hardly huge. you can easily fit that in a list in memory.

Comment: Ow okay. Yeah its probably just 1 Mb. But i thought that may be still big enough to consider an other way to do it

Comment: 1 Mb? Then it's not a  "huge file".

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the words are all ASCII, you’ll have a file with 6 bytes per row. This means you can read with a random offset into the file that’s a multiple of 6 (5 letters plus a newline):

```
from random import randint

with open("filename", "r") as f:
    f.seek(6*randint(0, 1000))
    print(f.readline())
```

Note that this only works if the line endings and characters are all single byte and so on. Any mistake and you will get half a word. You also need to know the length of the file.

Answer (score -3):

Pick a random value `n` from 1 to `L`, where `L` is the number of lines in the file, then iterate over the file and pick the `n`-th value; something like this:

```py
import random
import itertools

n = random.randint(1, 1000)
with open('words.txt', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    word = next(itertools.islice(f, n, None))
    word = word.strip()
```

The only condition is that you should know how many lines the file has beforehand.

With this method, you won't need to store the previous lines until you get the one you want.

Comment: Why exclude the first line?

Comment: @KellyBundy It could be a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). It doesn't really matter on a 10,000-lines file.

Comment: I don't think whether losing the first word matters is for you to decide. And for "BOM", I think using `utf-8-sig` would be better.

Comment: And this might pick n=L and thus crash.

Comment: @KellyBundy That's why they can change the code sample! The magic of open-sourceness.